# How to identify failed casts using dynamic_cast operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, dynamic-cast

`Scott Meyer` in his book `Effective C++` says `dynamic_cast` is used to perform safe casts down or across an inheritance hierarchy. That is, you use dynamic_cast to cast pointers or references to base class objects into pointers or references to derived or sibling base class objects in such a way that you can determine whether the casts succeeded.

Failed casts are indicated by a null pointer (when casting pointers) or an exception (when casting references).

I would like to get two code snippet showing the failed cast in the case of casting pointer and casting reference can be indicated.

Comment: Are you asking for examples of code that tests whether a pointer is null and of code that catches an exception?

Comment: No. I do not understand how casts could fail as mentioned by Scott. A code snippet would definitely help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast

Comment: @JamesMcNellis : Kindly remember we all start as beginners. I got the code snippet from Reed anyways.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

For pointers, it's a simple null check:

```
A* a = new A();
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);

if (b == nullptr)
{
    // Cast failed
}
```

For references, you can catch:

```
try {
    SomeType &item = dynamic_cast<SomeType&>(obj);
}
catch(const std::bad_cast& e) {
    // Cast failed
}
```

Comment: @LinuxPenseur The check is assuming that "a" has a valid value.  You'd have to check that first (for the allocation).  The dynamic_cast check is checking whether A can safely be cast to "B" - so the check is against `b` for `NULL` - ie: b is null and a is not null.

Comment: @ReedCopsey : What is meant my `safe cast`. In which situation can b become NULL ?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is used when a class is polymorphic (has `virtual` function) and it does run-time checks, returning a `NULL`pointer. Using `dynamic_cast` you are telling it to doexactly what you want instead of C-Style conversions where it tries various type of conversions. `dynamic_cast` is also used when you don't know the object to be converted, instead of `static_cast` that is used for non-polymoprhic classes and where both types on the conversion are known

Comment: @ViniciusHorta : I did not mean to see a text book definition which is not at all what i asked for

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: `new()` doesn't necessarily return a null pointer on fail, you may need to check for an exception here also. `b` will become `NULL` if `a` is not an instance of `B`.

Comment: @g-makulik: The normal version of `new` won't return a null pointer ever -- it'll either return a valid pointer, or throw an exception. To get a null pointer on failure, you use `new(nothrow) whatever;`

Comment: Please forgive a newbie question, but is `if (b)` equivalent to `if (b == NULL)`?

Comment: @Suzi it'd be the same as != NULL

Answer (score 6):

Based on the OP's comment (" I do not understand how casts could fail as mentioned by Scott."), the real question here is really something like: "how could a `dynamic_cast` fail?"

The time it would fail is when the target type does not match the dynamic type of the object. For a simple example:

```
struct A {
   virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {};

int main() { 
    A *a = new A;

    B *b = dynamic_cast<B *>(a);    // should fail
    if (b == NULL)
        std::cout << "First cast failed.\n";

    A *c = new B;
    b = dynamic_cast<B *>(c);       // should succeed
    if (b == NULL)
        std::cout << "Second cast failed.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here although `a` *could* point to an object of type `B`, it actually *does* point to an object of type `A`. When we try to do a dynamic_cast to get it to point to a `B`, that fails. In the second attempt, we again have a pointer that not only could *but does* point to an object of type `B`. Since it does, the dynamic_cast to `B *` succeeds in this case.

The basic situation doesn't change (much) for the reference case, just `a`, `b` and `c` become references instead of pointers, and we note the failure by catching an exception (which @ReedCopsey has already demonstrated well enough that I don't think I have anything new to add).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a complete example that shows how `dynamic_cast` can fail to produce a pointer.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Foo();
};

class B: public A
{
};

class C: public A
{
};

void test()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    A* pA = &b;
    B* pB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pA);  // this works OK, returns the expected pointer
    C* pC = dynamic_cast<C*>(pA);  // this returns NULL because B isn't a C
}
```

In the real world you'll be trying to cast pointers that weren't so straightforwardly created, perhaps they come from a `vector` for example.