# C++ virtual function override

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have a class that contains the following virtual method:

```
struct point {
    template<typename T>
    virtual typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<point, T>::value, double>::type distTo(T &other) const = 0;
};
```

The above doesn't work because:

```
error: templates may not be ‘virtual’
```

The plan is to specialize the class by making more specific instances of it like `point2D`, `point3D`. However, I only want the function to work with types of the same class. So if `point2D` where to inherit this class, the method `distTo` should only take parameter of type `point2D`. How can I accomplish this?

This is what I had tried before I did the above:

```
virtual double distTo(point& other) = 0;
```

But when I override this method in the `point2D` class and try to replace the parameter with one of type `point2D`, I run into compiler errors.

Thanks for your time

Comment: A virtual function can't be more template than its containing class. But if the containing class is template, so can be its virtual functions. On the other hand, a derived class CAN be more template than its base class, and provide a template implementation of its virtual functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirements make no sense for a static typed language such as C++.

Think about how would you be able to use your virtual function:

```
point2d p1, p2;
point3d p3;

point &p = p1;

p.distTo(p2); //ok?
p.distTo(p3); //error?
```

That is simply not possible, because at compile time the compiler will not know if `p` is a reference to a `point2d` or a `point3d`, only at runtime.

You could add an explicit cast and a runtime assertion if you do it wrong, but I think that it make little sense. Simply do:

```
struct point { /*...*/ };

struct point2d : point {
    double distTo(const point2d &other);
};

struct point3d : point {
    double distTo(const point3d &other);
};
```

And do not call `distTo` using base `point` references.

**UPDATE**: If you know that your list is homogeneous, but you don't know the cardinality, then you can do:

```
struct point {  
    virtual double distTo(const point &other) =0;
};

struct point2d : point {
    double distTo(const point2d &other) { /*...*/ }
    virtual double distTo(const point &other) {
        const point2d &other2 = static_cast<const point2d &>(other);
        return distTo(other2);
    }
};

struct point3d : point {
    double distTo(const point3d &other) { /*...*/ }
    virtual double distTo(const point &other) {
        const point3d &other3 = static_cast<const point3d &>(other);
        return distTo(other3);
    }
};
```

But beware! If you call `point::distTo` with a wrong object, the result will be undefined!

Comment: Because of polymorphism, I could have a number of these points in a list and all with the type `point`, then this solution will not work

Comment: @Smac89: There is no solution that maintains type safety and dynamic indirection.

Comment: @Smac89: But if you have a list references to `point`, what would you do with them? Call `point::distTo()` what would you pass to the function, a `point2d`?

Comment: No, the list would have been checked to make sure that all the points in the list have the same cardinality, so that you can still call `distoTo` for any pair of them. I understand the compiler cannot know this

Comment: If all the items in the list are actually `point2d`, then simply cast them to `point2d&` and call a non-virtual `point2d::distTo()`. If you don't know the cardinality but you are sure they are the same, then see my updated answer.

Comment: The idea for casting brought me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11510210/2089675)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. Furthermore, this is *completely incompatible* with dynamic indirection, as the compiler cannot statically verify the dynamic type (obviously). But the CRTP can only be used to *implement* the function, not declare it.

```
template<typename T> class Point {
public:
    double distTo(T other) {
        /* stuff */ 
    }
};
class Point2D : public Point<Point2D> {
    // distTo automatically defined
};
```

Fundamentally, the interface you are trying to declare is completely impossible because you're asking the compiler to statically typecheck dynamic types. There is no solution that offers all the properties you want.

Comment: Completely understand thanks very much. I was just thinking about the same thing but with java - the `Comparator` interface

Comment: @Smac89: Implementing that involves manually erroring on objects of the wrong type. The compiler cannot catch type errors on the non-generic version, and the generic version cannot be stored in a list in the way you want.

Comment: But then, `Point2D` and `Point3D` will not have a common base class, which may be irrelevant to the OP or very important, depending on their code base.

Comment: @rodrigo: Having the base class can't offer the interface he wants (at least for this function) so it's more-or-less immaterial.