# How to identify a specific derived class by pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance

I have a piece of code, that consists of an engine, a queue of pointers of requests processed by the engine, and a set of different types of requests, all of them classes - one 'most general' and a lot of variants.

Now, one of these request types requires a special handling.

```
class GenericRequest {};
class SpecificRequest1 : public GenericRequest {};
class SpecificRequest2 : public GenericRequest {};
class VerySpecialRequest : public GenericRequest {};
```

The queue just contains pointers (of type `GenericRequest*`) to instances. `GenericRequest` is instantiated too - instances of it appear in the queue too.

I need the engine to single out `VerySpecialRequest` and perform extra operations as it appears.

If I understood the answer involving inheritance in [How to identify failed casts using dynamic_cast operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510452/249618), in my case using:

```
VerySpecialRequest* result = dynamic_cast<VerySpecialRequest*>( queue_entry );

if(result != NULL) { /* process the special entry */ }
```

will catch instances of `GenericRequest` on top `VerySpecialRequest`, only filtering off `SpecificRequest1` and `SpecificRequest2`.

How can I go about identifying this specific child?

Comment: *"`GenericRequest` is not abstract"*, so you cannot use `dynamic_cast` on it. Make it polymorphic, and you would be able to do that (virtual destructor should suffice).

Comment: @Jarod42 "abstract class". I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @n.m.: From provided code, `class GenericRequest {};` -> no virtual methods.

Comment: The *Right Way To Do Things*™ is to add a virtual function to `GenericRequest` and implement special handling in `VerySpecialRequest`.

Comment: @Jarod42: possibly. Been quite a while since I was learning that, probably forgot. Edited to make more clear what I meant. It does contain virtual methods, doesn't use them (the most generic usage pattern doesn't require them).

Comment: @Jarod42 provided "code" is not even syntactically correct as is.

Comment: @n.m. if you want full code, that's about 1300 LOC just of the engine and requests, not including invocations where requests are made and actually running the engine. I don't think this would be very helpful. I could include just some declarations from the original, but knowing this site, it would just yield a hundred irrelevant questions pertaining to inner workings of the engine and properties of the requests specific to business logic.

Comment: No, I'm happy with the code skeleton as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will change minimally your example code:

```
class GenericRequest {
   virtual ~GenericRequest;          // the virtual destructor makes GenericRequest polymorphic
};
class SpecificRequest1 : public GenericRequest {};
class SpecificRequest2 : public GenericRequest {};
class VerySpecialRequest : public GenericRequest {};
```

As soon as GenericRequest contains a virtual function, it becomes a *polymorphic* class, as become all of its subclasses.

Once polymorphism is ensured, we can safely use `dynamic_cast`:

```
GenericResult *queue_entry;
...
VerySpecialRequest* result = dynamic_cast<VerySpecialRequest*>( queue_entry );
if(result != NULL) { /* process the special entry */ }
```

That's all. Either `queue_entry` actually pointed to a `VerySpecialRequest` object, and `result` will point to that object, or it pointed to a non derived `GenericResult`, or a `SpecificRequest1` or `SpecificRequest2`, and `result` will be a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the answer in the linked question never actually feeds a pointer to nstance of `A` to the `dynamic_cast<B*>`  (nor ever instantiates `A` for that matter) so it in fact didn't answer my question at all.

Comment: @SF.: yes it did. The pointer is always a pointer to a polymorphic base class, and the dynamic cast converts it to a pointer to the subclass **if the pointer was obtained by converting an address/a pointer to the expected class. My answer is not much more than a rewording of the other one...